# Black areas shown in my material

Tags: materials, uv

I added a .tga image to my basic material but I get black area's over my entire model. On the UV itself everything seems to be okay. They only thing I can think of is that I used the displace modifier after UVing but the UV still stayed the same after applying the modifier.

All the materials are basic Principled BSDF with a image added and specular turned to 0.

[image: User Image Showing Problem]

Comment: Two things come to mind: a bad UV unwrap or flipped normals? Turn on "Face Orientation" on the viewport overlays panel and make sure its all blue, then make sure your UVs are mapping those areas.

Comment: or maybe Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

Comment: Nothing wrong here.  It's hard to tell because of how the seems are drawn but those black areas are in the textures.

Comment: When I use the same texture inside the Unity engine everything appears as it should. Somehow this only occurs inside Blender..